# How to pack existing SQLite Database in MAUI app

Tags: sqlite, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I want to pack already existing SQLite database in MAUI .net app but not able to find the solution.

If that is not possible, can I call a function only once during the installation to create new database populate the data?

I know how to create SQLite and CRUD.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any assets you want into the project directory `Resources/Raw`. There is also a file `AboutAssets.txt` which explains how to access the files:

> Any raw assets you want to be deployed with your application can be
> placed in this directory (and child directories). Deployment of the
> asset to your application is automatically handled by the following
> `MauiAsset` Build Action within your `.csproj`.
>
> ```xml
> <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
> ```
>
> These files will be deployed with you package and will be accessible
> using Essentials:
>
> ```cs
> async Task LoadMauiAsset() 
> {     
>     using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("AboutAssets.txt");
>     using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
>
>     var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
> }
> ```

1. Store the database to deploy into the `Resources/Raw` folder.
2. On each application start check if the database exists.
3. If not **copy** it from the assets folder into the expected path

### Alternative

I recommend migration scripts each going from one version to next. You can set/get the current version in SQLite with [`PRAGMA user_version`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version) and execute the needed migration scripts until the final version is reached. So it does not matter from what version you will ever upgrade.

The migration scripts can be deployed as described above.